# Prestashop - create link to the category that a product belongs to

Tags: hyperlink, categories, prestashop

I'm fairly new at prestashop. On the home page I am using the "Specials Center" module which just displays a list of products that are on sale. I wanted to show which category the product belongs to. I edited SpecialsCenter.tpl and used this code:

```
<a href="#">Category: {$Specials.category}</a></h2>
```

This correctly displays the corresponding category name for which the specific product belongs to. See image: [Product with category](http://i.imgur.com/YVY38).
 The only thing I am having trouble with is creating a link to that category. Should be fairly simple but Prestashop forums seem so vacant. All questions. No answers. What is the variable to use to link to the category page?

Thanks for your help.

Having done a little more research...this is where I am now...

```
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$Specials.id_category}, {$Specials.category})}">Category: {$Specials.category}</a>
```

So this outputs this link: mysiteurl/0-laptops - this is partly correct, except the **category ID** is wrong. The id for the category laptops is 4. It should be this: mysiteurl/**4**-laptops. So the first smarty tag `{$Specials.id_category}` is incorrect. I need to know how to draw the category ID using a variable of some kind. So it should be something like this:

```
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink('category-id', {$Specials.category})}">Category: {$Specials.category}</a>
```

Thanks again!!! :)

Comment: There is a possibility that id_category is not found in $Specials. Try this, and you will see all values in $Specials: <a href="#">{$Specials|print_r}</a>

Comment: Thank you so much. That was helpful. I'm new to stackoverflow...I'm supposed to vote you up or something? :)

Comment: Hmmm...looks like I don't have enough reputation to do any voting! According to the faq. lol. Thanks again!! :) Will upvote you when I can vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND: Ah! Thank you Niclas Larsson - that was helpful! I should have thought about that! :) You were right, it was not pulling "id_category" the correct usage is as follows:

```
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$Specials.id_category_default} , {$Specials.category})}">{$Specials.category}</a>
```